# How baking soda help in indigestion of stomach?

Tags: acid-base, reaction-mechanism, salt

We have learnt that baking soda can be used for neutralizing excessive acid in stomach formed during indigestion.

And after some time we get a burp(CO2) after drinking baking soda solution.

So why we got that burp?
I got 2 answers in whom I am totally confused which one is correct :-

Answer 1. When we dissolve baking soda in water we know it as a basic salt(strong base weak acid salt) that's why it form H2CO3 by taking a proton (Hydrogen ion) from water , thereby releasing OH- ion in solution that help in neutralizing excess H+(hydrogen ion)  in stomach from HCl. And simultaneously keep forming H2CO3 upto the time we are drinking baking soda solution.

NaHCO3 + H2O---> Na+(spectator ion) + H2CO3

This H2CO3 dissociate to form H2O and CO2 , causing us burp.

H2CO3---> H2O + CO2(cause burp)

Answer 2. Sodium carbonate react with Hydrochloric acid.

NaHCO3(aq) + HCl (aq)----> NaCl (aq)+ H2CO3(aq)

Now this carbonic acid dissociate to form
Carbon dioxide cause burp.

H2CO3 ---> H2O + CO2 (cause burp)

**Now my doubt is " which is correct reason for release of carbon dioxide as burp after drinking baking soda?"**

1 or 2

**NaHCO3 is stomach is reacting with Water with which it is drinked with (dissolve in ) or HCl present in stomach to give CO2?As NaHCO3 can react with water and HCl both , so in stomach which reaction is going on ? Why?**

HCl referring here Hydrochloric acid present in stomach for digestion and activation of pepsin

Comment: Essentially the same thing as happens with baking soda and vinegar: you get carbon dioxide and water and sodium ions as spectators and the conjugate base of the weak acid.

Comment: @Maurice, why not 1? Bcuz we when  dissolve NaHCO3 in water  it will start forming H2CO3 which go along with water in stomach and dissociating simultaneously cause burp??? Also read the edit I made recently

Comment: @EdV sorry it's typing error , thanks and also can you elaborate your comment

Comment: @Ed V i think I have done all HCL into HCl

Comment: Dissolve NaHCO3 in water and observe it. Does it release a gas ? No, it does not. // You may find useful these links for text formatting ( not to be applied to titles ):
 [notation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) ,  [text + formula formatting](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  and 
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)

Comment: @ poutnik, it should create a little fizz according to equation , shouldn't it? Look                   
 https://bakinghow.com/baking-soda-and-water/#:~:text=Essentially%2C%20the%20baking%20soda%20reacts,acid%2C%20ultimately%20creating%20carbon%20dioxide.      Read it you will find that there written it produce CO2. Than how it is possible No fizz. Please explain sir.

Comment: BTW thanks for link. I will use it next time

Comment: Please note that hydrogen chloride ($\ce{HCl}$) and hydrochloric acid are not the same. See here for example: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrochloric_acid. You will see that both your options are incorrect as soon as you understand the difference.

Comment: @snijderfrey, I never mention anything about hydrogen chloride in question or have I??....And I know the difference sir. ..

Comment: Well, hydrogen chloride is written in your first equation below answer 2.

Comment: Oo.....look at edit in question

Comment: Hydrogen chloride is HCl(g,l,s). Hydrochloric acid is HCl(aq), fully dissociated to H+(aq) and Cl-(aq).

Comment: @poutnik , that what I have written in 1st eq. Below second answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The essential reactions of baking soda neutralizing an excessive stomach acid, irritating the upper digestive system, are:

$$\ce{HCO3-(aq) + H+(aq) <=>> H2CO3(aq) <=>> H2O + CO2(aq) <=> H2O + CO2(g)}$$

$\ce{Na+(aq)}$ ( from $\ce{NaHCO3(s)}$ ) and $\ce{Cl-(aq)}$ ( from $\ce{HCl(aq)}$ ) ions are "spectator" ions, forming solution of ionized $\ce{NaCl(aq)}$.

Comment: (+1) Finally! I thought this tempest in a teapot would go on and on. Thanks for putting it out of our misery!

Comment: @poutnik, nice answer but what about water in which I mix baking soda to drink can also react with NaHCO3 (1st ans) in stomach along with HCl  . Shouldn't it?

Comment: @SureshChandraPal Time for own thinking. Does water contain H+(aq) ? How much ?

Comment: @poutnik, yes it does . In a very small amount(if asking about self ionization of water)  But I have learnt that basic salt  can snatch off H+ from water leaving behind OH-   ,   so as much water is there  that much H+  NaHCO3can take from it......isn't it?    Look : Answer to Is NaHCO3 acidic or basic? by Mike Jones https://www.quora.com/Is-NaHCO3-acidic-or-basic/answer/Mike-Jones-2528?ch=15&oid=174685333&share=328c4e7f&srid=hrHyD7&target_type=answer .   Here you will find NaHCO3 can take H+ from H2O ,

Comment: no where mention it take H+ from self ionization..and a small amount of water contain a lot H2O thus lot of H+ it can snatch. Right??.

Comment: @SureshChandraPal Time to learn about quantitative acidobasic equilibrii.

Comment: @SureshChandraPal, Please find on the internet just how basic the bicarbonate anion is, and how much more acidic H+(aq) is compared to water. You really could accept this answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Your first equation is based on a non-existant reaction. I repeat it here : $\ce{NaHCO3 + H2O -> Na+ + H2CO3 + OH-}$.

No ! $\ce{NaHCO3}$ will very rarely produce $\ce{OH-}$ ions in water : concentration lower than $10^{-5}$ M, as pH is around $8.3 - 8.4$. On the contrary, it may react with $\ce{OH-}$ ions, but not produce them.

So your second answer is correct : $\ce{NaHCO3}$ reacts with $\ce{HCl}$ to produce $\ce{H2CO3}$, then $\ce{CO2}$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132008/discussion-on-answer-by-maurice-how-baking-soda-help-in-indigestion-of-stomach).